# How to fix conflicting requirements installing Nokogiri for Rails on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, bundler, nokogiri

Recently switched from a Mac to a PC and hit a wall with `bundle install`.

I get an error but I'm have trouble figuring out what it means and how to fix it. I searched through the GitHub issues and other StackOverflow threads, but none of the fixes suggested help me because they're focused on Linux mostly.

```
Bundler found conflicting requirements for the Ruby  version:
  In Gemfile:
    Ruby  (~> 2.6.5.0)

    pg was resolved to 0.21.0, which depends on
      Ruby  (< 2.5) x64-mingw32

Ruby  (< 2.5), which is required by gem 'nokogiri (>= 1.4.1)', is not available
in the local ruby installation
```

Comment: You have a gem / Ruby version mismatch. What Ruby version are you using (or trying to use)? Here is a guide that may help you answer my question: https://blog.arkency.com/which-ruby-version-am-i-using-how-to-check/

Comment: I'm using `2.6.5` which is the version listed in the gemfile.

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the `Gemfile.lock` file which fixed the issue.

The Ruby versions are fine at the project level, I knew this because the server runs on my Mac, so it was a Windows or machine-exclusive issue.

Answer (score -2):

Your version of Ruby is too recent for that project. Downgrade to Ruby `2.4.X` or update the gems of the Gemfile.